# Print function does not print anything while working to build CNN Architecture

Tags: pycharm, pytorch, ubuntu-18.04, python-3.7

I am learning image classification with CNN in Pytorch. While I started to build the CNN architecture I am getting 2 problem:

1. When I run my code I get the warning `-warnings.warn("train_labels has been renamed targets")`
2. I tried to print loss and accuracy using `print` function but it does not print anything.

Here is my code:

```
 def forward(self, x):
     out = self.layer1(x)
     out = self.layer2(out)
     out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
     out = self.drop_out(out)
     out = self.fc1(out)
     out = self.fc2(out)
     return out
     from torch import optim
     model = ConvNet()
     criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
     optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
     total_step = len(train_loader)
     loss_list = []
     acc_list = []
     for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):

          outputs = model(images)
          loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
          loss_list.append(loss.item())
          optimizer.zero_grad()
          loss.backward()
          optimizer.step()

          total = labels.size(0)
          _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
          correct = (predicted == labels).sum().item()
          acc_list.append(correct / total)
          if (i + 1) % 100 == 0:
           print("Epoch [{}\{}], Step [{}\{}], Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.2f}%"
                    .format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, i + 1, total_step, loss.item(),
                            correct / total) * 100)

        # Test the model
          model.eval()
          with torch.no_grad():
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            for images, labels in test_loader:
                outputs = model(images)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                total += labels.size(0)
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

            print("Test Accuracy of the model on the 10000 test images: {} %".format((correct / total) * 100))
```

Comment: lines from model.eval() are inside the for loop. Add the following lines in the end   `if __name__ == '__main__': forward(1)`

Comment: I fixed it. It was indented block error.Now it's working.